# Export podcasts from iTunes as OPML, or some other way?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, opml

I recently bought a new computer, and installed iTunes 9 on it, mainly to subscribe to podcasts. All my regular podcasts are saved as subscriptions in iTunes om my old computer.

Is there any way to save myself entering in all the subscriptions individually on my new computer, by maybe exporting the podcast list as an OPML file, or otherwise saving that list out of iTunes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-mouse click on Podcasts (on the left side of itunes) and pick Export...
Then change the Save as type to Podcast Subscription files (*.opml).

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks. And if anyone is stuck on how to import that OPML file back into iTunes (because there is no corresponding right-click option to Import Podcasts), simply drag the OPML file into the Podcasts window and away you go. The only pain is that iTunes will assume that you have not downloaded the latest versions of any of your subscriptions, and will start to do so.

Answer (score 2):

In iTunes 11 open podcasts and then File → Library → Export playlist.