# How to not lose iTunes Podcast Subscriptions when rebuilding machine

Tags: itunes, podcasts, rebuild

I'm going to do a clean install of Windows 7.  I would like to not loose all of my selections in iTunes for podcasts that I have subscribed to.  How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/53889/export-podcasts-from-itunes-as-opml-or-some-other-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to select the podcast section in iTunes, then File | Export. Save the file where ever you want it saved, but make sure to change the file type to OPML. I have done this many times and works perfectly. After the rebuild, you can import the OPML file and all of you subscriptions return.

The only negative is that it doesn't save your unlistened shows.

Comment: I have no File > Export, but do have File > Library > Export Playlists.  This generates a Podcasts file which you can export as .xml or .opml.  The description for .opml is listed as "Podcast Subscription files", so that looks pretty encouraging.

Comment: Sorry, I was working from memory and/or a different version.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on Podcasts in the Library and select `Export...`

In the save window choose "Podcast Subscription files" as the file type.  This will save all your subscriptions in an [`.OPML` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPML) which is the standard for a collection of RSS feeds.

Once you have re-installed iTunes drag-and-drop the `.OPML` file on to iTunes to re-subscribe to all your podcasts.

Answer (score 1):

Backup your itunes music folder, and restore it once you have re-installed.

My version is shorter, but here's a different write on it that I found...
http://uneasysilence.com/how-to-backup-your-windows-itunes/

Answer (score 0):

Are subscriptions associated with your iTunes account?  If so, when you reinstall iTunes you will be fine.

If they are not associated with your iTunes account (and only stored locally as I suspect), your best bet would be to copy down the names of the podcasts, and when you reinstall iTunes, re-subscribe to the pertinent podcasts.

Comment: That doesn't backup your existing content, and itunes doesn't "push" content down unless you ask for it.  So if he was to format his HD, he would lose all of his data.  He needs to backup his itunes folder..

Comment: How does one associate podcast subscriptions with an iTunes account?  What are the steps?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes also has the ability to backup and restore the entire library (podcasts included) to DVDs.